# Condition based on value from Get-Content Measure-Object -Character Doesn't Execute as expected

Tags: powershell

I'm fairly new to powershell and don't understand why the powershell script below outputs the following:

Under 5000 characters

779892

I'm confused as to why the else branch is executed rather than the if when $TotalChars is equal to 779892. Can anyone help?

```
$TotalChars = (Get-Content test.txt | Measure-Object -Character)

if ($TotalChars.Characters  > 5000)
{
    Write-Host "Over 5000 characters"
    $firstHundredLines = Get-Content test.txt -TotalCount 100
    Set-Content -Path test.txt -Value $firstHundredLines
}
else
{
    Write-Host "Under 5000 characters"
}

$TotalChars = (Get-Content test.txt | Measure-Object -Character).Characters

$TotalChars
```

Comment: You should take a look at PowerShell’s actual operators https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7

Comment: Thank you @DougMaurer

Comment: Ditto to what Doug Maurer stated, but also, why are you reading a file, attempting grad partial content from the said file, then completely overwrite the same file? Set-Content overwrites not appends. YOu'd use Add-Content for appends. You also cannot write to a file that is open, or where Windows has not released all the file handles to it. You are not checking for the state of the file prior to Set-Content. What is your use case.

Comment: I'm a novice to Powershell. I have a markdown file that I need to restrict to a maximum of 5000 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Doug Maurer I found the fix was to use -gt instead of >

"PowerShell doesn't use the greater than (>) or less than (<) characters because they're used for output and input redirection" https://www.itprotoday.com/powershell/windows-powershell-operators